# Delete Asp.Net Databse Connection Tutorial. Receiving CS103 error code

Tags: sqldatareader

I am new to programming and found these great tutorials on the Guru99.com site. Under the insert, update, Delete Asp.Net Database Connection Tutorial I was able to make the connection to the database successfully where the message came back "Connection Made".
The problem I am having is under the ASP.NET Read Database using the SQLDataReader. When I added the code and ran the program, I got a CS103 code which is The name 'sqlquery' does not exist in the current context. I thought that had to rem out the response.write and ccn.close statements thinking that the connection needed to be opened and still got the same error code. I hoping to find someone who are familiar with this tutorial. Here is my code:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String connetionString;                //Variable declaration
            SqlConnection cnn;

```
        connetionString = @"Data Source=BMIS-JHanlon3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DemoDB;User ID=sa;Password=demo123";   //Set connection string

        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString); //Assign connection

        cnn.Open();                          //open and close the connection
       // Response.Write("Connection Made");
       // cnn.Close();

        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataReader dataReader;
        String sql, Output = " ";
        sql = "Select TutorialID,TutorialName from DemoDB";

        command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

        dataReader = sqlquery.ExecuteReader();
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            Output = Output + dataReader.GetValue(0) + " - " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + "</br>";
        }

        Response.Write(Output);
        dataReader.Close();
        command.Dispose();
        cnn.Close();
    }



}
```

}

Comment: You might try using command instead of sqlquery.

Comment: Where exactly do you declare the sqlQuery parameter?

Comment: ExecuteReader() is a method of a Command object. Your command object is named command, not sqlquery. (You created the command object like this: SqlCommand command; command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);)

Comment: Honeyboy Wilson, you were correct I replaced sqlquery with command. So the line now reads dataReader = command.ExecuteReader(); SomeStudent, as you can see my response that command solution did work. There was no declaration of the sqlQuery parameter. Thanks for both of your responses.

Comment: Honeyboy Wilson, thanks for your explanation. I got it now